# Best way to validate records in table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have to write a stored procedure to validate customer names.

There was a case where a customer's last name "Miller" was inserted into every single record. So I have to create a stored procedure to make sure if does happen again. This stored procedure will catch this issue and raise the issue.

I am not sure how to approach this if is possible to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you know that is not right last name? As far as I know, name can be anything and it is almost impossible to create a name validator. Like some people don't have last name!! Some have 2-byte characters in names. Basically, name is a free text. Validating is not the right thing to do. Fun fact: There are more than 100k Abhishek's in the world, so you can't rule them out as well :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically for validation like this, you'd look for patterns you've identified as problematic e.g., First_name and Surname are the same, names have only one character (an initial), etc.

But note that these should only be used to flag for review/potential update, rather than automatic denial/removal. For example, I knew someone called 'Joy Joy' (when they got married, their adopted surname unfortunately matched their first name).

So fundamentally, you need to identify the patterns you want to look for, then code them into the stored procedure. There's no set process out there that can help you with that.

Ideally, the stored procedure would be used to help identify issues - and then patterns that are useful are then transferred to your client-facing code to validate the data before entry into the database.

Comment: I have to think best way to write pattern, it should be as flag and sent to for verification.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to cleanse that old data and add a `CHECK` constraint on the name column. As a workaround you may use triggers, but it less performant in general. Another way to workaround old names, if your DBMS supports this feature, is to add calculated column, where you will show only "new" names or good "old" names and add `CHECK` constraint on that column.

But name validation is something unreal, there are deliberately [strange examples](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%9E%D0%A7_%D1%80%D0%92%D0%A4_260602).